# How to update CollectionView with TableView "Did Select Row At" method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a ViewController that contains a collectionview and a tableview. I would like to be able to press a row in my tableView and update the collectionView with new images. I'm not sure how I can reference the collectionView in this scenario.

I'm assuming I would have to put some code in my "DidSelectRowAt" method in my tableView, and pass data using dictionaries. Anyone have any idea? thanks!

[image: viewController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method and pass your latest dictionary to collectionView Dictionary

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourCollectionViewDict = arrDict[indexPath.row]
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried triggering `collectionView.reloadData()` from your tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: I havent actually. Would i do if indexpath.row == 0 { //insert code then collectionView.reloadData()}?

Comment: How would i grab the imageView in the CollectionViewCell to use in my DidSelectMethod? Sorry for the questions @pesch

Comment: It wasn't sure for me if your collectionView was on the first row of your tableView. If so, then yes. Check if indexPath.row == 0 and then reload the data on that collectionView